# Cleaning metal after stripping paint

Tags: paint, cleaning, metal, paint-removal

I have stripped the paint off my mailbox, which is probably some kind of steel, using `KleanStrip`. However, as you can see, there is still residue. What should I use to clean it? I am hesitant to use water not to cause rust.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The absence or red or brown corrosion products indicate it is not likely steel. A magnet will end the guessing. It could be steel with an exceptionally thick zinc galvanizing. Or zinc or aluminum die casting. Water will not corrode it significantly. Apparently a brass mail door and a lock that is really good chrome plating, stainless or German Silver ( white brass).

Comment: "I doubt water will have much affect on it." Is that the answer - "use water it won't rust the mailbox", or is that "water won't affect the residue", or something else? While this all seems like useful info, I'm struggling to find the actual answer here. Please clarify.

Comment: I just checked with a magnet (always forget that) and it is nonferrous. Does that mean I can wipe it with a damp cloth (water)?

Comment: @amphibient I would manually sand it with fine-grit sandpaper to get rid of the residue from the paint stripper, then wipe it clean with the damp cloth.

Comment: I agree, sand and paint or not paint.  Check that the paint is compatible with zinc and aluminum.

Comment: I sanded it already

Answer (score 1):

You could just lightly sand it with fine sandpaper and use a damp cloth to wipe off. nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning o repainting it? If so, ignore the residue and don't sand it, you will make the surface MORE smooth and the paint will have LESS adhesion.

Comment: Won't there be a reaction between the paint and the stripper residue? They don't seem compatible. Actually, coarser sandpaper will scratch the metal but a better sticking surface for paint. Don't do it though.

Comment: Not when it is dry. The stripper" is typically a strong solvent like MEK (Methyl Ethyl Ketone), Ethylbenzene or Toluene that has some buffering agents added to it to slow down the volatility (meaning how fast it evaporates) so that it has time to react to the paint. Once it volatizes, it's gone and the residue is just solids left over from the paint and the buffering agents.

Comment: I see. If not bothered by the residue solids, there is no harm to apply paint directly. Yeah, I did sand every time after stripping though, and paint adhered if there was no grease or stain :)

Comment: Sanding doesn't make a surface smoother as far as paint is concerned. Sanding makes it more rough and better for paint.  Also, it removes junk that would flake off, which will make paint fail.